# HTML Label is will not cross 1st col in a colspan 2 cell

Tags: html, css, formatting, label, html-table

I have an HTML table on a website I am maintaining. To fit the new layout, I needed to make an input box's cell colspan 2. The problem is, there is an accompanying label that needs to stay on the same line.

When I make the change, the label does not cross the "boundary" line of the first column.

Ex:
Cols

|-------|--------|--| - Layout

|----------------|--| - Colspan="2"

|[=======]*-|--| - [===]Input box, * Where label should be

|------*---------|--| - * Where label is when I float right

HTML:

```
<td id="TdPhyAddress2" class="style10" colspan="2">
    <input id="txt1" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="476px" style="float:left"></input>
    <asp:label id="lbl1" Runat="server" style="float:right" ></asp:label>
</td>                  
<td></td>
```

For some reason, the label will not cross the "1st" column line, even when floated right. I use Visual Studio, and even in designer view, I cannot drag and drop the label in the space between the input and the end of the cell.

I do not understand why this is happening? Shouldn't the cell colspan apply to all elements in that cell?

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

float right ignores most containing elements and simply floats to the right as far as it can determine the width of parent elements to be.
Try:

```
text-align: right
```

instead.

Comment: I am getting the same issue with text-align: right, unfortunately

Comment: I would need to see more of the HTML then as the issue must be external to this snippet. If you try the 2 cases with a basic example you will see that text-align: right will always align to the right side of the available cell's space.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a couple things that may help.
You don't have any `<tr>` tags so that could cause some styling issues besides just semantics.
You are also missing a `</td>` after the input so you just have one big cell with an empty cell after it.

```
<tr>
    <td id="TdPhyAddress2" style="float:left" class="style10" colspan="2">
            <input id="txt1"runat="server" Height="20px" Width="476px"></input>
    </td>

    <td style="float:right">
            <asp:label id="lbl1" Runat="server"></asp:label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

[Here is a link to a codepen demonstrating the code.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYexMK)
I believe this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I have the <tr> tags in my actual code, I just forgot to include them in my example. Your solution would work, except I can't have the input and label in separate cells. This site is designed with functionality on the cell with id="TdPhyAddress2" (background color change) and this needs to affect both the input and label elements. It is not something easily changed, unfortunately.

Comment: Ah okay. Is it possible to change the ID to a class and give both cell the class? I'll give it another shot when I get home tonight and get back to you!

Comment: Thank you for your help! I actually fixed it. I still do not know what was causing it, but I just copied the code from another part of the site (virtually identical code) and pasted it in place, just changing the ids to what they should have been set to. It then displayed correctly, even though the code is identical. I'm not asking questions, it's working now! Thanks again!